# Animate for ConTeXt

Tags: context, animate

Is there an alternative of LaTeX's animate package for ConTeXt? A search here and on the web mostly yields (dated) alternatives using embedded movie players or javascript, which I would prefer to avoid. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: There's an `animation` module, but I'm not sure whether or not it does what you expect. See the following example: `\usemodule[animation]
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\starttext 
\startanimation[menu=yes]
  \dorecurse{10}
    {\startexpanded
       \startframe
         This is\recurselevel
       \stopframe
     \stopexpanded}
\stopanimation
\stoptext` (works on Acrobat Reader DC)

Comment: Oh, nice! But it crashes Okular :-(.

Comment: @AlexG This happens with many other ConTeXt features: color emoji font support isn't showing in Evince, for instance. I think the better reader to test is Adobe's, willy nilly. If you think this may be a bug, ask the mailing list. 

Comment: Here is one example: https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/metapost-animation/

Comment: @JairoA.delRio JS-driven animation support has been added to Okular recently. It works quite well (at least for `animate`-generated animations). So, asking the mailing list might be worthwhile.